# JSP, GET and POST parameters

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am required to do some small tasks with JSP; being very new to JSP I was wondering if there was any possibility to get only *GET* or only *POST* parameters from the HTTP request.

I have seen [ServletRequest.getParameter](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html) (and alikes) but it seems that those methods get both GET *and* POST parameters. Is there a way to get only one of them, without parsing the URL or the request body myself? And if not, is there any precedence rule which values overwrite which (like POST parameters always overwriting GET parameters)?

Comment: This is actually a code smell. What is the functional requirement? Why not just give the GET and POST ones a different name?

Comment: @BalusC: It is actually a security issue. Requiring specific parameters to be only sent as POST parameters (or GET respectively) improves the security for the end user. And I don't really want to blindly accept any kind of a parameter after I have learned to avoid that in years of creating web applications before.

Comment: Then just determine the request method or implement a servlet which enables you to execute code on a certain method only. See Bozho's answer.

Comment: Well, see my comment to exactly that answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Generally, requests should better be handled in servlets. They have `doGet(request, response)` and `doPost(request, response)` methods, to differentiate the two.

If you really insist on doing it in a JSP, you can differentiate the methods using [`request.getMethod()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getMethod%28%29). It would return `GET` or `POST`.

Since this is homework, I guess the point is to learn how to use servlets and their `doX` methods, so do it that way.

**Update:** You *can* get the query string ([`request.getQueryString()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getQueryString%28%29)), which is only the get parameters, and parse it, but I wouldn't say that's a common and good practice.

Comment: Yes, but remember you can include URL parameters on POSTs, so the question about precedence and origin still applies, even in a servlet (which, of course, is what a JSP becomes).

Comment: We are required to use JSP; and no, don't imply anything about the reason behind it just because it is homework. The course just randomly brings up new technologies and wants us to do something with it without giving previous instructions etc. And yes, as T.J. Crowder said, you can still set GET parameters in a POST request.

Comment: In the context of MVC, it is recommended to handle requests via servlets which act as controllers. JSPs are basically views.

Answer (score 4):

In JSP, you can look at the request object to determine what kind of request it was (GET or POST), but there's only one parameter map.

Answer (score -2):

Try [Servlet + JSP]. At Servlet you can choose between doPost() or doGet()