# Is there a way to request.getParameter for only POST variables in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp

In PHP there is $_REQUEST, $_GET, and $_POST. What if I want to only get POST variables in JSP to prevent someone from putting the variables in the url? Is there away to do this? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSP, GET and POST parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178041/jsp-get-and-post-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

The query string is available from the HttpServletRequest object - so you know what was on the URL. You can therefore filter out anything in the getParameterMap() that was in the query string, leaving only stuff that was posted.

Comment: If you want to prevent people sending in data they should not, then you could consider including a secure hash of all the immutable data if your POST is going to use such. For example, if the post has a user-id as a hidden field, you can include a hash of the user id and some salt as a second hidden field and be sure no one has spoofed the user id.

Answer (score 0):

Your HttpServletRequest object has a getMethod() property which will tell you if it was a GET or a POST. You could just reject all GETs.

I don't think that <form action="mypage?foo=bar"> actually works, that is, I don't think you can have both POST and GET parameters at the same time. I could be wrong, though.