# How does a JSP page handle both GET and POST method?

Tags: java, jsp

When writing a servlet, we usually override the `doGet()` and `doPost()` method inherited from the `HTTPServlet` class.

But when writing a JSP, all the template HTML, scriptlet and expressions goes into the `_jspService()` method. We don't have a chance to make the `doXXX()` methods.

So how does a JSP page handle `GET` and `POST` and all the other HTTP-methods?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178041/jsp-get-and-post-parameters

Answer (score 0):

This becomes clear if you look at how HTTPServlet does call your `doGet()`, `doPost()` and so on (just the important lines...)

```
protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
  String method = req.getMethod();

  if (method.equals(METHOD_GET)) { 
     doGet(req, resp);
  } else if (method.equals(METHOD_POST)) {
     doPost(req, resp);     
  } else if (method.equals(METHOD_PUT)) {
     doPut(req, resp);  
  }
  [...]
}
```

That's exactly how you could do it in JSP as well - as `_jspService()` is more or less the same as `service()` is in `HttpServlet`. Check the `request.getMethod()` and do things according to the method called.

So instead of having different convenience-methods like `HttpServlet` does, JSP is a more raw implementation of Servlet - but you can still do the same things.