# jquery ajax POST method doesn't execute function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm new to JavaScript and AJAX, and am trying to to create a simple web app consisting of a server and a JavaScript/JQuery client. It has an input field and a button. After pushing the button, a POST request consisting of the text in the field should be sent to the server, and the page should be changed to the response from the server. If there is an error, the page should be changed to an error message.

Here's my partial solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
        .input {
            width: 600px;
            height: 100px;
        }
        </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#send").click(function(){
                 $.post("http://localhost:8080/Web/", $("#text").val(), function(result, status){
                    $( "#content" ).html(result);
                 });
            });
        });
    </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <textarea class="input" id="text" placeholder="Write text to send to server" textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
        <p>
        <button id ="send">Send request</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This does not change the content of the page to the response from the server (which I've tested works). Putting in an alert except of changing the content of the page also doesn't work. I've read up a bit on AJAX JQuery, but didn't seem to manage to get it right.

Thank you

Comment: What does `result` look like?

Comment: You most likely need to send the data as a key/value pair, eg `{ text: $('#text').val() }`, although this will depend on how you've set up your server side code. What exactly is the response? Check the console to see the status code too

Comment: It is just a text string. At this moment it just says "Hello World 1"

Comment: Rory McCrossan: Console says
"Failed to load http://localhost:8080/Web/: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."

Comment: I set up the server as a jsp. Reading from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178041/jsp-get-and-post-parameters question makes me think maybe I should rather have it as a servlet? Since I'm not sure JSP handle POST well

Comment: I'm assuming you are running/opening the `html` file as is and consuming the `api/web service`. If so, you would have to include the `html` file as part of the `web/api` project or make changes in your service to allow `CORS`.

Answer (score 1):

You can [read the API Docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

The AJAX `post` method must have key valued object, e.g:

`{ text : $("#text").val() }`

or Form Data object in the second parameter.

I hope this helped.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering.
Changing the POST call line to $.post("http://localhost:8080/Web/", { text : $("#text").val()}, function(result, status){
did not help, and the same status message is returned.

From the docs, I really don't see why I have to send it as a key value object, since the parameter data says: "A plain object or string that is sent to the server with the request."